# Boot DVD not recognized on desktop - sony vaio

Tags: installation

I have a working Windows XP sony vaio desktop on which I wanted to install Ubuntu 12.10 using DVD on an available partition.  I created the dvd from iso and made sure the boot order is correct in bios.  The ubuntu dvd is not recognized by the computer and doesnt boot or install.   I used the same DVD on another  two machines (desktop and a laptop) running vista and windows 7, it does boot and asks me to install.

However, on this Sony vaio desktop it doesnt boot.  I tried windows installer and it works but very slow, and sometimes hangs and i dont want to use a virtual drive and run on windows, I would prefer to run ubuntu on a native partition on this machine.

while in XP, the dvd shows as blank.  When checked on windows 7 the same dvd shows up all install files of Ubuntu.

Is there a solution for this at all?  The bioes does not allow to boot with usb drive for me to try that.

Answer (score 0):

could it be that your DVD-drive doesn't recognise the DVD-R ? 
Since you work with XP it could be possible.

I would try to burn the 12.04.2 (5 years support and kernel 3.5 included) on a **CD-R** and retry to install on your computer. 
Let's keep our fingers crossed this will help you futher.

b.t.w. is your fysical RAM memory large enough (1Gb at least) for running Unity - Ubuntu ?

Comment: Thank you Joris, I will try 12.04.2 Yes I have 1.5 GB on this machine.